# trying to get property on non object in laravel using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm coding a simple comment section on my project and from now it's working pretty good except at the moment of edit or delete a fresh new comment. I can create, edit and delete all the comments using ajax but to delete or edit a new comment i have to refresh the page. Reason? Trying to get property of non object. Looks like i can't get the comment id of new comments, to get those id's i have to refresh the page..

This is my ajax.

Create a new comment:

```
$('.send').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var dataSerialize = $('#add-comment').serialize();
       var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
       $.ajax({
          method: 'post',
          url: urlPostComment,
          data: dataSerialize,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data) {
             console.log(data); 
             if( data.success )
             {
                $('#post-comments').append(
    "<section class='comment-list"+data.id+"'><article class='row'><div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs'><figure class='thumbnail'><img class='img-responsive' src='/uploads/avatars/"+data.picture+"' /></figure></div><div class='col-md-8 col-sm-8'><div class='panel panel-default arrow left'><div class='panel-body'><header class='text-left'><div class='comment-user'><i class='fa fa-user'></i> "+data.name+" "+data.lastname+" <time class='comment-date p-l-10'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> "+data.timestamp+"</time></div></header><div id='comment-post' data-commentid='"+data.id+"'><p id='display-comment' class='store-comment p-t-10'>"+data.comment+"</p></div></div><div class='panel-footer list-inline comment-footer'><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='edit-comment' class='edit-comment' data-id='"+data.id+"' data-name='"+data.comment+"'>Editar</a> <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='delete-comment'class='delete-comment' data-id='"+data.id+"' data-name='"+data.comment+"'>Eliminar</a></div></div></div></article></section>"
                );

                toastr.success('Comment created.', '', {timeOut: 7000})
                $('#comment-new').val('');

             }
             else {
               toastr.warning(" "+ data.message +" ", '', {timeOut: 7000})
             }

          }, 
          error: function () {
            toastr.warning('Message couldn't be sent, Try again.', '', {timeOut: 7000})
          }, 
          complete: function () {
            $btn.button('reset');
          }
       });
    });
```

My update Ajax:

```
var commentId = 0;
var divcomment = null;


$('body').on('click', '.edit-comment', function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     divcomment = this.parentNode.parentNode;
commentId = $("#comment-post",event.target.parentNode.parentNode).data('commentid');
    var commentBody = $(divcomment).find('#display-comment').text();
    $('#comment').val(commentBody);
    $('#edit-comment').modal();
    });

$('body').on('click', '#modal-save', function(){
var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
var comment = $('#comment').val();
$(this).button('loading');
$.ajax({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: urlEdit,
    data: {
        comment: comment,
        commentId: commentId,
        _token: token,
        _method: 'PUT',
     },
    dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function (msg){
    if (msg.success === true) {
        $(divcomment).find('#display-comment').text(comment);
    }
    $btn.button('reset');
    $('#edit-comment').modal('hide');
    toastr.success('Comentario editado.', '', {timeOut: 7000})
});
});
```

And my Delete Ajax code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete-comment', function(){
$('#delete-comment').modal();
$('#comment-value').text($(this).data('id'));
});

$('body').on('click', '#comment-delete', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
$(this).button('loading');
$.ajax({
type: 'delete',
url: urlDelete,
data:{
  'id': $('#comment-value').text(),
  '_method': 'delete',
  '_token': token
 }
})
.done(function(response){
$('.comment-list' + $('#comment-value').text()).remove();
$('#delete-comment').modal('hide');
toastr.success(" "+response.success+" ", '', {timeOut: 7000})
$btn.button('reset');
})
.fail(function(){
$btn.button('reset');
$('#delete-comment').modal('hide');
toastr.warning('Message couldn't be sent, try again.', '', {timeOut: 
7000})
})
});
```

UPDATE:

Variables:

```
var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
var urlPostComment = '{{ url('comments/' .$post->id) }}';
var urlEdit = '{{ url('comments/update') }}';
var urlDelete = '{{ url('comments/' .$comment->id) }}';
```

About this last one `var urlDelete = '{{ url('comments/' .$comment->id) }}';` i don't know why if post doesn't have a comment it gaves me an error "undefined variable id" or "undefined variable comment"

Controller Logic:

```
public function store(Request $request, $post_id)
{
  if(!$request->has('comment') || empty($request->comment))
  {
    return response()->json([
      'message' => 'No puedes enviar un comentario vacío.',
      'success' => false
    ]);
  }

  $post = Post::find($post_id);
  $comment = new Comment();
  $comment->comment   = $request->comment;
  $comment->approved  = true;
  $comment->user_id   = auth()->id();
  $comment->user->profilepic = $comment->user->profilepic;
  $comment->post_id   = $post_id;
  $comment->save();
  return response()->json([
    'comment' => $comment->comment,
    'user_id' => $comment->user_id,
    'post_id' => $comment->post_id,
    'picture' => $comment->user->profilepic,
    'name'    => $comment->user->name,
    'lastname' => $comment->user->last_name,
    'timestamp' => $comment->created_at->diffForHumans(),
    'post_slug' => $post->slug,
    'success' => true
  ]);
}

public function update(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'comment' => 'required'
    ]);

    $comment = Comment::find($request['commentId']);
    if (Auth::user() != $comment->user) {
        return response()->json([
            'errorupdate' => 'No hemos podido actualizar tu comentario, intenta nuevamente',
            'success' => false], 200);
    }

    $comment->comment = $request['comment'];

    $comment->save();
    return response()->json(['new_comment' => $comment->comment, 'success' => true], 200);
}

public function destroy(Request $req)
{
  $response = [];

  $comment = new Comment;
  $comment = Comment::find($req->id);

  if (Auth::user() != $comment->user) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

  if ($comment->delete()) {
      $response['success'] = 'Comentario eliminado.';
      $response['subject'] = $comment;
  }

  return response()->json($response);
}
```

Comment: post your controller logic as well

Comment: what is `urlDelete` ? Is not defined anywhere.

Comment: i will post all the variables and controller logic, let me update the post

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: @SapneshNaik there is my var defined

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay there's all the logic